# Can I play PUBG on Remix OS?

Tags: remix-os

Is there any special task needed to run PUBG on RemixOS Android 6.0? I've downloaded and installed PUBG on RemixOS but after Tencent logo, a just black screen is coming. I've also installed Google Play Games properly on RemixOS. Is something missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think u can't play with remix os its dead now try phoneix os as i see few playing on Phoenix os and nox player as well.